# Spring Cloud Eureka Detecting KeyCloak port instead of intended port where service is running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using `KeyCloak` for `OAuth2` authentication and it is working as expected.
Now I wanted to use Eureka for service discovery. So, I added respective `spring cloud eureka` dependencies. I started the `Eureka server` and then started the API service (another spring boot application). API service is using `KeyCloak` for authentication. I was able to register the API service as Eureka client & the API service is listed in the Eureka server. But, the problem is with the API port identified by the Eureka server.  The API service is started at port `9090`, but Eureka is considering KeyCloak port `8080` instead. So, I'm getting error since no service located at port `8080`. Please help me understand whats going wrong here. Thanks!

**maven dependencies in API service project**:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9090
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8791/eureka/
```

**spring boot application starter class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GrpcServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**security config**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(
            final KeyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter keyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter) {

        final JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(keyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    KeyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter keyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {
        return new KeyCloakGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        // Uses local Keycloak instance running on port 8080 with the realm: TestRealm
        final String endpointURI = "http://localhost:8080/realms/grpc-oauth/protocol/openid-connect/certs";
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(endpointURI).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider(final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter) {
        final JwtAuthenticationProvider provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder());
        provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
        /*
         * Add the authentication providers to the manager.
         */
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider) {
        final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }

    @Bean
        // Configure which authentication types you support.
    GrpcAuthenticationReader authenticationReader() {
        return new BearerAuthenticationReader(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken::new);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please say what versions you are using and your configuration

Comment: @spencergibb I have mentioned maven dependencies and Eureka specific configuration above. Also mentioned how I use KeyCloak in the code. Note that I'm not using `keycloak spring boot starter` dependency.

Comment: Can you post complete error with stacktrace. Also, check output of http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration